# Azure - restrict access to app service only

Tags: security, azure, azure-web-app-service

Ive created a website in Azure and I want to allow users to login and use the app, but im slightly confused by azure active directory access.  I want users to only have acces to the web app, not to the portal.  Users will be from within my organisation and from outside it so its vitally important that access is locked down, If a user somehow ends up at the azure portal they must not be able to access it.  If I set users up in our active directory, wont they be able to login to the azure portal too ? I want to take advantage of authentication as a service and hand over authentication and multi factor authentication to azure but everytjhing Ive read so far seems to suggest If i use azure active directory, users will be able to acess the Azure portal too, is this correct or am i misinterpreting the information ? Are there any step by step guides available for these sorts of scenarios ?

Comment: If you haven't granted them explicit access to the portal, then how would they get access to the portal? Are they members of the subscription itself (e.g. admin)? If not, you'd have to explicitly grant permissions on a given set of resources (resource group). But maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry, its just my initial confusion having not developed with azure before and i couldnt find any clear guidance on the issue.  My access to the portal is restricted by our IT department so im unable to explore the possibilites myself

Answer (score 1):

> If i use azure active directory, users will be able to acess the Azure
>   portal too, is this correct or am i misinterpreting the information ?

No, your users will not have access to Azure Portal (rather Azure Subscription as Azure Portal is an application using which a user manages one or more Azure Subscriptions) unless you grant them permission to access it. In order for your users to have access to Azure Portal, you would need to grant them permissions explicitly to do so. In the new portal, you do it by assigning roles (e.g. Owner, Contributor, Reader etc.) and in the old portal you do it by making them co-administrators.

Unless you do this, when they login into Azure Portal all they will see is a message stating no Azure Subscriptions were found.

Comment: I do have one other question though, if we setup users to the app and we give them a login using azure active directory, will the usernames all have to be in our domain ?  eg  someuser@ourdomain.com

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but I believe you would need to map your domain to Azure AD domain name (yourazureadname.onmicrosoft.com). Otherwise the username would be username@yourazureadname.onmicrosoft.com). HTH.